# Prettier didn't appear on status bar in VS Code for minified file on server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I installed the prettier extension on VS Code and it works perfectly for the javascript codes on my local machine. But when I'm debugging some minified javascript on server, prettier didn't appear on the status bar, the Ctrl+Alt+F shortcut didn't work, Ctrl+Shift+P can't find the "Format Document" option either. If I copied that minified javascript content and save it as a js file on my local machine, then opened it in VS Code, prettier will show up on status bar and works well.

Edit:

The problem occurred when I'm in debug mode, the minified js file location is shown as something like "\http:\localhost:8176\XXXX.js". Also when I tried to edit that file, a message "Cannot edit in read-only editor" will show up. In this case how can I use prettier on it so that I can read and debug the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that a .js file (extension?), probably not recognized by the tile type

Comment: Yes it is a .js file.